# MySQL "Statement may not be safe to log in statement format" warning

Tags: mysql, replication, log, warning

What is the meaning of the following MySQL warning:

```
Statement may not be safe to log in statement format.
```

I have some tens of thousands of these statements every day in my `mysqld.err` file, and I'm not sure where should I begin my investigation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that your binary log format [`binlog_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) is STATEMENT, which is the default binary log format.

`STATEMENT`-based format logs the statement issued, while `ROW`-based format logs how individual tables were changed. The problem with `STATEMENT` logging is certain statements cannot guarantee that the same data written on the Master will end up on the slave.

An example:

```
INSERT INTO audit (CURRENT_USER());
```

You can get a good idea of different types of these non-deterministic statements by looking at [how the](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-mixed.html) `MIXED` format handles switching to `ROW`-based format. `ROW`-based format writes a lot more data to the binary log, but is much safer.

Answer (score 3):

There is another reason for `“Statement may not be safe to log in statement format” warning`

My employer has a DB Client who is always running a query like this

```
DELETE FROM mydb.mytable WHERE ... LIMIT 1;
```

This query will succeed on a DB Server. However, if you are using MySQL Replication, this could present data inconsistency problems because when either `UPDATE ... LIMIT` or `DELETE ... LIMIT` statement is executed, the row order for the `LIMIT` is never guaranteed to be the same.

In other words :

- `UPDATE ... LIMIT` may update a row on the Master but a different row on the Slave
- `DELETE ... LIMIT` may delete a row on the Master but a different row on the Slave

The way around this would be to do [**what @DTest just recommended : Change the binlog_format to ROW.**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25361/877) (+1 for @DTest for going straight to the solution)